# Magento2 multistore setup, getStore()->getCode() shows default

Tags: magento2, multistore, magento-2.1.1

Add **store codes to urls** is set to yes.

Store code is: test.

- Default homepage for that store loads correctly: home cms page for
  that particular store.
- In the menu the store code is added to the urls:
  www.example.com/test/men.html

But when I add this code in a template file (one called in the homepage for example):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$store = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
echo "Code: ".$store->getStore()->getCode(); 
echo "Name: ".$store->getStore()->getName();
```

I get the default store code and default store code name.

**Why is that? I didn't edit the index file or htaccess.**

If I would go ahead and add this to the index file:

```
 $params = $_SERVER;
 $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'test'; 
 $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
 $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
 $bootstrap->run($app);
```

Then it will show the right store code, but I don't want to edit the index file as the client must be able create the stores in the admin without us editing files.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the objectmanager was creating a new instance of the `StoreManagerInterface`. If I change it to

`$objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')`

then I get the right store code.